# itte in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, instruction-set, thumb

What does the following line do in arm assembly:

```
000031e6        2916    cmp r1, #22
000031e8        bf1a    itte    ne
```

I get the first line (comparing r1 to 22) but what about the second line (I've never seen the itte command before and googling returned nothing)

Answer (score 55):

It is the ARM's IF-THEN-ELSE instruction, which was introduced in the Thumb-2 instruction set.  (Based on your specific example above, it would have been helpful if you had shown the next 3 instructions that followed the `ITTE` instruction, you'll understand why when you're done reading this answer.)

This instruction is used for handling small sequences of conditional code, up to 4 instructions.  Think of it as a different way of implementing the ARM's conditional execution (e.g. BNE  - the branch instruction is only executed if the zero flag is not set).

The benefit of it is that it avoids the penalty of taking a branch (presumably you've learned about pipelines etc.)

The instruction is a bit involved but once you wrap your head around it, it's pretty elegant.

It takes the form:

`IT<x><y><z><cond>`

where `x`, `y`, and `z` are optional, and must be either `T` (for "then") or `E` (for "else").  `<cond>` is any of the conditions such as `NE` or `EQ` or `GT`, etc. that are reflected in the APSR flags.

So you always have one `T` following the `I` (the instruction is `IT` after all!), and then 0-3 `E`'s or `T`'s.  For each `T` and each `E`, you must have a subsequent instruction in the same order that matches up.  Each matching subsequent instruction must have conditions that match up with the `IT` instruction.

Bear with me, I know this is confusing.   I'll give a couple examples here to illustrate.

The minimal form of the instruction would be something like:

```
IT LT
SUBLT.W  R2, R1
```

In this case, if `LT` is true (per the APSR flags), the subtraction will take place.  Notice the `LT` in the `SUB` matches the `LT` in the `IT` instruction.

A full-blown example would be something like:

```
ITETT NE
ADDNE R0, R0, R1
ADDEQ R0, R0, R3
ADDNE R2, R4, #1
MOVNE R5, R3
```

So we have THEN ELSE THEN THEN (`TETT`), with `NE` condition.  Notice in the 4 conditional instructions that follow (4 instructions, 1 each for `TETT`), the "THEN" instructions have the `NE` condition, and the "ELSE" instruction (the 2nd instruction after the `IT` instruction - remember the E was the 2nd of 4 E's and T's) has the opposite condition.  It cannot be anything else, i.e. it would be an error if it was something like `LT` instead of `EQ`.  `EQ` is the opposite of `NE`.

So if `NE` is true, then instructions 1, 3 and 4 would be executed.  Otherwise (`EQ`), only instruction 2 (`ADDEQ`) would be executed.

I've given examples of 1 and 4 instructions, but you can also have 2 `(IT{T,E}`)and 3 instruction (`IT{T,E}{T,E}`) forms as well.

Finally, to bring home the point, I'll give an example of how the following C code can be implemented using this instruction:

```
if (R4 == R5)
{
  R7 = R8 + R9;
  R7 /= 2;
}
else
{
  R7 = R10 + R11;
  R7 *= 2;
}
```

converts to

```
CMP R4, R5
ITTEE EQ
ADDEQ R7, R8, R9    ; if R4 = R5, R7 = R8 + R9
ASREQ R7, R7, #1    ; if R4 = R5, R7 /= 2
ADDNE R7, R10, R11  ; if R4 != R5, R7 = R10 + R11
LSLNE R7, R7, #1    ; if R4 != R5, R7 *=2
```

That should give you enough to chew on for a while.

Comment: Nice overview. Some background for benefit of readers who might not be all that familiar with ARM: 32-bit ARM opcodes each had condition bits to control whether the opcode should execute or not. When the original Thumb variant was developed, there wasn't room in the 16 bit opcodes to dedicate to conditional execution bits, so only branch opcodes had conditional execution (like many other CPUs). Thumb2 added these 'conditional opcodes' to permit short sequences of conditional execution (ie., to prevent short conditional code sequences from killing the pipeline).

Comment: Great explanation! But what if I want more instructions in the conditional block (not limited to 4)? The only way is using branch?

Answer (score 4):

In simple words `ITTE` executes following 3 execution as IF THEN {} THEN {} ELSE {} based on above `cmp` instruction.

In ARMv6T2 and later architectures, you can use the `IT` instruction for conditional execution. In architectures before ARMv6T2, there is no `IT` instruction and therefore Thumb instructions cannot be executed conditionally except for the `B` branch instruction.The assembler checks the IT instructions, but omits them on assembly to ARM code.

For your solution lets first understand syntax of simple `IT` instruction (introduced in Thumb 2)of ARM assembly ,which is base of `ITTE`.

`IT{pattern} {cond}`

*If-then, sets the execution conditions for up to 4 following instructions 
 can be any combination of up to three T(then) and E(else) letters,the first instruction following IT is always cond (T)                    Instructions that can modify the program counter must be last in an IT block*

The `then` conditions must match the condition code, and any `else` conditions must be the opposite condition.The table below shows the condition codes and their opposites:

[image]

Let's understand another `cmp` instruction.

`CMP Rn, #imm`

*Rn must be a Lo register. imm range 0-255.
These instructions update the N, Z, C and V flags according to the result.*

Remember : **`IT` allows one to four following Thumb instructions (the IT block) to be conditional or you can say here ITTE is used for handling small sequences of conditional code, up to 4 instructions.**

Simple examples

Ex 1:

```
cmp r1, #22      Compare r1 value with 22 
IT  EQ           Read this as If EQual Then ADD R1,R1,#1
ADD R1,R1,#1     <- This will only be executed if above r1 value equal to 22(means when z condition flag is equal to 1)
```

Ex 2:

```
cmp r1, #22       Compare r1 value with 22
ITE EQ            Read this as If EQual Then ADD R1,R1,#1 Else ADD R0,R0,#1
ADD R1,R1,#1     <- This will only be executed if the Z condition flag is 1
ADD R0,R0,#1     <- This will only be executed if the Z condition flag is 0
```

> What ITTE do ? is your question here

```
   CMP   R1, #22       Compare r1 value with 22
   ITTE  NE            Read this as IF NotEqual Then ADD R1,R1,#1 Then ADD R0,R0,#1 Else ADD R2,R2,#1
   ADD R1,R1,#1     <- This will only be executed if the Z condition flag is 0
   ADD R0,R0,#1     <- This will only be executed if the Z condition flag is 0
   ADD R2,R2,#1     <- This will only be executed if the Z condition flag is 1
```

Here `ITTE` imposes the NE condition on first two following instruction and the EQ condition on the next.

**NOTE:** Any branches that exist in an IT block must be the last instruction in the block.Taken reference from [here](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/09/30/condition-codes-3-conditional-execution-in-thumb-2)
Following example will be having undefined behaviour because branch instruction is used in middle of branch instruction.

```
ite     eq  
blxeq   some_label  @ UNPREDICTABLE during an IT block.  
movne   r0, #0
```

Correct way to implement the above would be to put the mov before the blx, as follows:

```
ite     ne  
movne   r0, #0  
blxeq   some_label  @ Ok at the end of an IT block.
```

---

For more info [THUMB-2 Instruction set reference manual](http://read.pudn.com/downloads159/doc/709030/Thumb-2SupplementReferenceManual.pdf)   Page 4-92

```
IT{x{y{z}}}<q> <Firstcondition>
```

`<x>` condition for second instruction in IT block

`<y>` condition for third instruction in IT block

`<z>` condition for fourth instruction in IT block

`<q>` specifies optional assembler qualifiers on the instruction

Two qualifier defined here :

```
       .N  Meaning Narrow. Assembler has to choose 16-bit encoding for the instruction if it is not possible then error.

       .W  Meaning Wide. Assembler has to select 32-bit encoding for the instruction if is not possible then error.
```

`<Firstcondition>` Condition for first instruction in IT block i.e EQ, NE,CC,CS.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to the part of the `IT` (`if-then`) instruction family: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0006e/QRC0006_UAL16.pdf (second page). The basic instruction is `IT` and then you have `T` for "then" and `E` for "else" to give `ITTE` and a condition code of `NE` == "not equal".

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the If-Then family of instructions (which is the only way to use conditional execution for Thumb-2 code)

Check out this link:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cjabicci.html

Comment: Ok, so what're the instructions actually saying?

Comment: OT: I you know some japanese, that line is hilariously fitting :)